# NMaximize not substutiting parameters of objective function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

NMaximize is not substituting parameters of its objective function. Is there a way to fix that? I have a three line program that exhibits the problem.

```
f[r_, x_] := Exp[-(x + r*Cos[x])^2]
obj[r_] := NIntegrate[f[r, x], {x, -1, 1}]
NMaximize[obj[r], r]
```

The objective function is defined for all r, and it can be easily computed.

```
In[47]:= obj[-1.34]
Out[47]= 0.698409

In[48]:= obj[0]
Out[48]= 1.49365

In[49]:= obj[0.54]
Out[49]= 1.29793
```

But when it is passed to NMaximize, it produces a bunch of warnings that look as follows:

```
"The integrand E^-(x+r Cos[x])^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-1,1}}"
```

Notice the explicit 'r' in the expression in the warning message, where r is the free variable in the optimization. So it appears that NMaximize is not substituting for r. It eventually comes up with the right answer, but only after a bunch of warnings as above. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Try to use `obj[r_?NumericQ] := `

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f, r, obj, x];
f[r_, x_] := Exp[-(x + r*Cos[x])^2]
obj[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[r, x], {x, -1, 1}]
NMaximize[obj[r], r]
(* {1.49365,{r->-1.25605*10^-8}} *)
```